# Debian machine not sending mails (PHP)

Tags: email, debian, php

I have a local vagrant debian machine hosting a Symfony php application which should sends mails with `Swiftmailer`.

When I move this app to a pre-production or production server mails are sent, so the application is doing its part properly.

Some time ago I think I saw in some log (I don't remember which one and was too busy to stop and analyze it in that moment) something related to *not enough permissions in mail queue or similar*, but I'm unable to find this message or any configuration related to it now.

My `php.ini` has these lines, first one is commented (I don't use mail function), mail log appears to be empty:

```
;sendmail_path =
mail.log = /var/log/mail.log
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There were some  issue with debian and  sending e-mail from sf. 
I don't  remember what was that , but  solution for  me was to spool emails, and  send  it  from command line (cron)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/spool.html